# New installation of Tridion 2011 SP CMS server gives error

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We are having Tridion 2011 SP1 environment up and running with one CMS server and one CDS server.  Today we installated new CMS server and pointed it to existing SQL Server database.  We used same MTSUser, same database credentials. Installation went smooth, but when we try to access CMS server we are getting 9 error as below.

1) The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

2) Loading list of languages failed.

```
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

3) Loading list of locales failed.

```
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

How to troubleshoot ?
We are able to access SQL Server database using ODBC.

Comment: This Q should really be on server fault as it is not programming related, but rather to do with installation of server based software, please consider posting it at http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tridion

Answer (score 4):

Use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to watch HTTP traffic when you load the Tridion GUI, and find the requests that are failing.

From here you could use [WCFTestClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get more specific details on the errors and the available bindings.

My guess is IIS Configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to suggest you to think a bit out of box. As errors are more specific to WCF service. so configure tracing and see what things are going wrong with the webservice.
This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). After all I will again recommend you to see server logs for more details. I or someone else can better help you , if you can share  logs here.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Tcm Service Host (windows service) running?